# How to correctly overload operators?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload operators in a class. But I can't get it to work.
The compiler sends me a lot of errors. Like:

**CS0019: Operator '`+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'**

or

**CS1020: Overloadable binary operator expected**

This is my code:

```
//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class DataObject<T> 
{
    private T data;

    public static void operator =(DataObject<T> a, T b)
    {
         a.data = b;
    }
    public static DataObject<T> operator +(DataObject<T> a, DataObject<T> b)
    {
        return a.data + b.data;
    }

    public static T operator +(DataObject<T> a, T b)
    {
        return a.data + b;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Int : DataObject<int>
{     
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Calc
{
    public Int Add(Int a, Int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public void Add(Int a, Int b, Int result)
    {
        result = a + b;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int a = new Int();
        Int b = new Int();
        Int result = new Int();

        Calc calc = new Calc();

        a = 5;
        b = 7;

        calc.Add(a, b, result);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);


        a = 3;
        b = 6;

        result = calc.Add(a, b);
        Console.Write("\n result=" + result);        

    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how to do this correctly?

Note: I only need 'T' to be an "int" or "float" data type.

Thank you!!

Comment: That's not going to work because `T` could be anything including classes that do not define the `+` operator.  You'd need to define it in your `Int` class where you know the type is something that has a `+` operator.  Alternatively you could create an abstract `Add` method and call that and force the child classes to define how the generic types should be added.

Comment: @juharr abstract `Add` method kind of defeats the purpose of this, doesn't it? The purpose of this is to _not_ have to declare an operator in every subclass by using that generic class.

Comment: That was the idea in the beginning. Inheritance of operators. But now I know that this is not possible to do. The Add method is just a test to check that an Int instance could be handled as an integer and simultaneously as an object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot overload the `=` operator in C#. `=` is simply not one of the [overloadable operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading#overloadable-operators). If you want to be able to do something like this:

```
a = 5;
b = 7;
```

The closest thing is to use an implicit conversions:

```
public static implicit operator DataObject<T>(T b) 
    => new DataObject<T> { data = b };

...

DataObject<int> a = 5;
DataObject<int> b = 7;
```

Note that the semantics of this is a little different from overloading the `=` operator in the way you wanted. This creates a new instances of `DataObject<int>`, rather than mutating `a` and `b`. Your second overload of `Add` won't work as it is. You would have to make `result` an `out` or `ref` parameter.

Furthermore, your whole design requires that there is a `+` operator defined for `T`, which isn't always the case, and there is no [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) that constrains `T` to "types that has overloaded `+` operator" in C#.

You seem to have made it generic so as not to repeat the boilerplate code of writing these operators, but operators really *do* need to be redefined in every type - if they are all inherited from a parent class, then they would all return the parent class, not themselves. `Int + Int` would return a `DataObject<int>`, not an `Int`. Do you really want that? C# has no self-types so you can't tell it to "return whatever the subclass is". Also, does it really make sense to add one type of `DataObject<int>` to another type of `DataObject<int>`?

Anyway, your `Int` is better suited to be a non-generic struct:

```
public struct Int
{
    private int data;

    public static implicit operator Int(int b) => new Int { data = b };
    public static Int operator +(Int a, Int b) => new Int { data = a.data + b.data };

    public override string ToString() => data.ToString();
}
```

`Calc` can be like this:

```
public class Calc
{
    public Int Add(Int a, Int b) =>  a + b;

    public void Add(Int a, Int b, out Int result)
    {
        result = a + b;
    }
}
```

Finally `Main` can be like this:

```
Int a = 5;
Int b = 7;
Int result;

Calc calc = new Calc();

calc.Add(a, b, out result);
Console.Write("\n result=" + result);


a = 3;
b = 6;

result = calc.Add(a, b);
Console.Write("\n result=" + result);
```